# Matrix exponential of a $3\times 3$ Matrix

Tags: matrices, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

I know that the exponential matrix of a $2\times 2$ matrix ($M$) by regarding the Euler relation is:

$$e^{-iM\hat{n}.\sigma}=\cos(M)\sigma_0+i\sin(M)\hat{n}.\sigma$$

where $\sigma=(\sigma_x.\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ stand for the well-known $2\times 2$ Pauli matrices and $\sigma_0$ is identity matrix of size $2$.

So my question is, What would we say about a $3\times 3$ matrix? is there such a simple way to find the exponential matrix of a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

For the subclass of skew-symmetric matrices there is a similar formula (*Rodrigues' rotation formula*), generally not. However, there are certain simplications for nilpotent and idempotent matrices. The usual way makes either use of the *Cayley–Hamilton theorem* or diagonalization.

Comment: I use a 3*3 Hermitian Matrix. Not skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: Then all I know is that this matrix is diagonalizable for sure and its matrix exponential will be Hermitian again.